# Symfony2 Doctrine, displaying entities from db under conditions

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have 3 tables that stores information of packages that comes from the warehouse.

Table 1 (main):

```
id | pkgno | barcode | weight
```

Table 2 (sub):

```
id | mainid | boxno | rackno | batchno | inqty
```

Table 3 (shipment):

```
id | subid | shipdate | blno | outqty
```

How would I query for rows of data that only displays under the condition that when `inqty` subtracts `outqty` does not equal to 0 (so 1 or more)?

This is the query that I started with:

```
SELECT
   s.id as subid, s.rackno, s.boxno, s.batchno, s.inqty,
   m.pkgno, m.barcode, m.weight
FROM
   Bundle:Main m
LEFT JOIN
   m.sub s
WHERE
   m.pkgno = :pkgno
```

So this would give me all the ones with the package number regardless of the quantities. How can I set it so that when something like $currentqty = $inqty - $outqty, if($currentqty > 0 ) then display data? I know how to do it in simple php, but not quite sure about Symfony2.

EDIT: more explanation: So not all of the Sub table entities have a Shipment entry, that is if that package has not been shipped yet then it is null. I'd like to have the condition that the current quantity would take the empty data (null) as a 0. Therefore, if Sub does not have Shipment entry, then `inqty` would subtract 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution via the `coalesce()` function by setting null values to 0.

```
SELECT
  s.id as subid, s.rackno, s.boxno, s.batchno, s.inqty,
  m.pkgno, m.barcode, m.weight,
  ss.outqty
FROM
  Bundle:Main m
LEFT JOIN
  m.sub s
LEFT JOIN
  s.ship ss
WHERE
  m.pkgno = :pkgno
AND
  (s.inqty - coalesce(ss.outqty, 0)) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

[Copied from the doctrine docs](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.x/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-select-examples)

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT u FROM CmsUser u WHERE ((u.id + 5000) * u.id + 3) < 10000000');
```

So you can do arithmetic using columns by wrapping each arithmetic operation in parenthesis. So just join the three tables and subtract your two values.

```
WHERE
    table2.outqty IS NOT NULL AND
    (table2.inqty - table3.outqty) > 0
```

Comment: Would I need to join the third table?

Comment: Yes, if you use a left join then it will join the tables and if a row doesn't exist in the joined table for the corresponding record in the other table then the value will be NULL for the column. If you don't join there's no way to relate the data across the different tables.

Comment: doesn't seem to be working.. Nothing is displaying. Here's how I have the query: http://pastebin.com/HbBBYeaK